# Problema Inicializar Lista para validação ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Tenho uma action que recebe um ficheiro do utilizador.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateFicheiro(FicheiroViewModel model)
{
   var listaDeFicheirosJaAnexados = servico.obtemficheirosJaAnexados();
   model.ficheirosJaAnexados = listaDeFicheirosJaAnexados.toList();

  if(!modelState.IsValid)
  {
     ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "erro!");
     Return View(model);
  }
}
```

Verifico se o ficheiro ja existe na base de dados, se existir o model deve ser inválido e deve mostrar uma mensagem ao utilizador a dizer que o ficheiro já existe. Mas não é o que acontece, pois a listaDeFicheirosJaAnexados esta sempre vazia.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
   if(listaDeFicheirosJaAnexados.contains(ficheiro)) 
      yield return new ValidationResult("ficheiro ja existe na base de dados");           
}
```

Parece que o método Valide só valida valores que recebe da view. 
É possível remediar isto se passar a lista de ficheiros ja anexados para a view, esconde-la através de css e depois verificar se o ficheiro já existe na lista ou não, mas não me parece a solução ideal.

Também posso criar um método especifico e passar-lhe a lista, mas isso iria fazer com que o meu controlador ficasse com mais 3 ou 4 linhas de código, e honestamente também não me parece a forma mais correta do resolver o problema.

O que eu queria mesma era que quando o método Validate fosse chamado, esse método já tivesse acesso a lista sem ser necessário passa-la através da view.

É possivel fazer isto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível, mas se você deseja alterar a model que está recebendo na action você precisa limpar o `ModelState` e depois revalidar novamente.

Primeiro é importante que a sua `ViewModel` implemente a interface `IValidatableObject`

```
public class FicheiroViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Ficheiro { get; set; }
    public List<string> FicheirosJaAnexados { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        if (FicheirosJaAnexados != null && FicheirosJaAnexados.Contains(Ficheiro))
            yield return new ValidationResult("ficheiro ja existe na base de dados");
    }
}
```

Já na sua controller, você precisa utilizar o `ModelState.Clear();` e o  `TryValidateModel(model);` para fazer a sua verificação.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateFicheiro(FicheiroViewModel model)
{
    //Limpa o ModelState
    ModelState.Clear();

    //Manipulando a model
    var listaDeFicheirosJaAnexados = new List<string> { "teste"};
    model.FicheirosJaAnexados = listaDeFicheirosJaAnexados;

    //Executanto novamente a validação
    TryValidateModel(model);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)       
        return View(model);

    // Inclua o seu código para regra de negócio e persistência.
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    //Destino da ActionResult no caso de sucesso
    return View("Index");

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]